# Jquery Ajax function setInterval - console error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I wrote jquery code with `$.ajax` which calls PHP function. I set also `setInterval(function_name, 5000)` but when I started the page console log shows so many mistakes whose count doesn't stop increasing. Because of this right now I also have a problem with the memory I am in the red zone. 
[image]

When I don't set Interval there are no errors.
Here is my Jquery code!

```
$(document).ready(function game_request() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'profile.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      'gamer': 1
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $("#gamerequests").html(response);
    }
  });
  setInterval(game_request, 5000);
});
```

My jQuery calls the PHP code `perfectl`. The problem is only the errors.

Comment: You're setting an Interval over and over again. Call `setInterval` once, or use `setTimeout` instead.

Comment: @ChrisG G oh you right thanks I am going to correct it

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
function game_request() {
  $.post('profile.php', {
    'gamer': 1
  }).done(function(response) {
    $("#gamerequests").html(response);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(game_request, 5000);
});
```